# What should be the number of boundary conditions of a PDE

Tags: pde, finite-element, boundary-conditions

As far as I know, for getting a unique solution to a PDE we should impose some boundary conditions to the PDE. ["The number of required auxiliary conditions is determined by the highest order derivative in each independent variable. "](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Method_of_lines)

My questions are: In any numerical method, especially in finite element method, is it valid:

1-) to use more boundary conditions than the highest order derivative in each independent variable.

2-) to use less boundary conditions than the highest order derivative in each independent variable.

For example:

1-) [In this article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00607-010-0138-4) and [in this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1007570410003308), while the highest order derivative of a spatial variable is in third order authors used two boundary conditions for that variable.

2-) [In this article](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/aaa/2014/819367/) while the highest order derivative of a spatial variable is in third order authors used four boundary conditions for that variable.

I can increase the number of articles like this.

Comment: You should take into account that some (homogeneous) boundary conditions are satisfied by the weak form of the PDE. These are termed _natural_ boundary conditions.

Comment: I am aware of that but I think the issue is not relevant with natural bc's. Also what about the numerical methods that do not use weak form such as collocation methods?

Comment: They can be written in weak form. Select a Dirac delta as weight in your weighted-residuals form.

Comment: They may be written in a weak form ok. but also they widely used directly and I see in some papers that the number of boundary conditions do not match with the order of pde. On the other hand as far as I know, all of the boundary conditions (natural or essential) must be specified at the time that the PDE problem is specified.

Comment: I'm afraid in this generality, the only answer to your question can be "as many as necessary to have a unique solution". Note that the articles you link to are about *nonlinear* PDEs, for which there's no single theory.

Comment: A well posed problem (with a unique "analytical" solution) is defined before discretisation as PDE's + BC's. How a well posed problem maps to a numerical algorithm, especially in the case of non linear PDE's, is too complex to be caught by your simple question. The only general guidance in my opinion is *computability* of a numerical solution, but also *convergence* of the numerical solution to the analytical one. Why look for simple general rules, if no single theoretical framework exists?

Comment: The referee report on my paper pushed me to ask this question. Although I considered a nonlinear pde in the paper  the referee claimed that the number of  boundary conditions should be equal to the order of highest derivative of spatial variable. But I understand from the comments above that there is not certain rules for nonlinear pdes .